# Arbitrary depth patterns/rules

Tags: replacement, functional-style

*Temporary message: I am now really confused. I am not sure how using Power and Unevaluated together works in the examples below.*

While answering [this question](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23714/4330), I stumbled upon the following.

We have

```
Power[Unevaluated[
  Power[Power[Power[Power[Power[Times[1, a1], a2], a3], a4], a5], 
   a6]], a7]
```

-> Power[Power[Power[Power[Power[Power[a1,a2],a3],a4],a5],a6],a7]

Where there seems to be some rule involving deeply nested patterns at work (correct me if I'm wrong). Compare this with

```
Power[Unevaluated[
  Power[Power[Power[Power[Power[Times[2, a1], a2], a3], a4], a5], 
   a6]], a7]
```

-> Power[Unevaluated[Power[Power[Power[Power[Power[Times[2,a1],a2],a3],a4],a5],a6]],a7]

Where nothing happens. Note also that

```
a2 = 3;
Power[Unevaluated[Power[Times[2, a1], a2]], a3]
```

-> Power[Unevaluated[Power[Times[2, a1], a2]], a3]

But that

```
Clear[a1, a2];
a1 = 3;
Power[Unevaluated[Power[Times[2, a1], a2]], a3]
```

-> Power[Power[6,a2],a3]

**Most importantly**, note that

```
Clear[a1, a2, a3, f];
f[1] = 2;
Power[Unevaluated[Power[f[1], a2]], a3]
```

-> Power[Power[2,a2],a3]

Whereas

```
Clear[a1, a2, a3, f];
f[] = 2;
Power[Unevaluated[Power[f[], a2]], a3] // FullForm
```

-> Power[Unevaluated[Power[f[],a2]],a3]

We have

```
FullForm /@ 
  Trace[Power[Unevaluated[Power[Power[Times[1, b], c], d]], e], 
   TraceOriginal -> True] // Column
```

->

```
(*output*)
HoldForm[Power[Unevaluated[Power[Power[Times[1,b],c],d]],e]]
List[HoldForm[Power]]
List[HoldForm[e]]
HoldForm[Power[Power[Power[Times[1,b],c],d],e]]
HoldForm[Power[Power[Power[b,c],d],e]]
List[HoldForm[Power]]
List[HoldForm[Power[Power[b,c],d]]]
List[HoldForm[e]]
HoldForm[Power[Power[Power[b,c],d],e]]
```

I am not sure if what to conclude from this.

Note that

```
Power[Hold[Times[1, 2]], 2] // FullForm
```

-> Power[Hold[Times[1,2]],2]

so that Times is of course not cleared if there is a function with attribute HoldAll surrounding it. Note that the test functions below also depend on this.

**Not so important: Tools**

The following are tools to play with larger expressions like this

```
(*warning! might clear unexpected variables!*)
Clear @@ Names["arg*" | "a" | "b"]

SetAttributes[holderToken, HoldAll];
tester = And[First[#] == {}, Length[#[[2]]] == kkkk + 1, 
    Last[#] == {}] &;
headFinder =
  Function[
   ReplaceAll[
    Unevaluated@Unevaluated@
      Cases[
       #,
       head, Infinity, Heads -> True
       ]
    ,
    {{head -> Unevaluated}, {head -> Power}, {head -> Times}} 
    ]
   ];

expression :=
  With[{compoWithHeldArg =
     Unevaluated @@
      (
       DeleteCases[
        Hold@
         Evaluate[(Composition @@

             Array[With[{argu = Symbol["arg" <> ToString[#]]}, 
                Function @@ {argu, Power[argu, a[#]]}] &, kkkk])[
           holderToken[Times[1, b]]]]
        ,
        holderToken, Infinity, Heads -> True
        ]
       )
    }
   ,

   Power[compoWithHeldArg, a[0]]

   ];
```

We then have

```
kkkk = 12;
tester@headFinder@expression
```

-> True

and

```
kkkk=12;
expression // FullForm
```

-> Power[Power[Power[Power[Power[Power[Power[Power[Power[Power[Power[Power[Power[b,a[12]],a[11]],a[10]],a[9]],a[8]],a[7]],a[6]],a[5]],a[4]],a[3]],a[2]],a[1]],a[0]]

and we see that

```
     Unevaluated @@
      (
       DeleteCases[
        Hold@
         Evaluate[(Composition @@

             Array[With[{argu = Symbol["arg" <> ToString[#]]}, 
                Function @@ {argu, Power[argu, a[#]]}] &, kkkk])[
           holderToken[Times[1, b]]]]
        ,
        holderToken, Infinity, Heads -> True
        ]
       )//FullForm
```

-> Unevaluated[Power[Power[Power[Power[Power[Power[Power[Power[Power[Power[Power[Power[Times[1,b],a[12]],a[11]],a[10]],a[9]],a[8]],a[7]],a[6]],a[5]],a[4]],a[3]],a[2]],a[1]]]

Where the Times is still present. So indeed applying Power[#,2]& to the expression above clears the Times.

**Deep pattern**

If we don't want to make any replacements, but just a deep pattern, we can recursively define a pattern as follows

```
Clear[patt];
patt = (_?AtomQ) | f[x_ /; MatchQ[x, patt]];
```

We then have

```
MatchQ[f[f[1]], patt]
```

(-> True)

**A function that acts a bit like Power**

Maybe something similar is going on with Power. That is, there is some pattern that searches in a deep way (maybe some kind of expressions that it can simplify), but the rule applied is trivial. I am confused and I thought the Times that was found was actually replaced by the same rule that (/whose pattern) found it. Now I am not sure if we should even speak of a rule in this case.

I can make a function that works (at least a bit) like Power in very limited cases.

```
ClearAll[shortCondition]
SetAttributes[shortCondition, HoldAll]
shortCondition[x_] := 
 MatchQ[Unevaluated[x], 
  HoldPattern[
   Times[___, 1, ___] | power[xxxx_ /; shortCondition[xxxx], _]]]

ClearAll[power]
power[x_ /; shortCondition[x], n_] := power[x, n]
```

We then have

```
power[Unevaluated[power[Times[1, 2], e]], d]
```

-> power[power[2, e], d]

-> power[2, 2]

Whereas

```
power[Unevaluated[power[Times[2, 2], e]], d]
```

-> power[Unevaluated[power[Times[2, 2], e]], d]

However, I think we should conclude from the Trace further above that Power works a little differently.

**The new question is**: How can we simulate the behavior of Power, especially the aspect of it that seems to apply rules deeply in the expression that is one of its arguments.

.

.

.

.

.

**Old text, which seems to distract now**

The more complicated problem of also making a non trivial replacement seems very difficult, but I'd still like to know if somebody knows if there is a way.

If we also want to make a replacement , that makes things difficult. In the example in which f has a recursive pattern, we might want to replace the atom found by 0. In the example of power we might want to replace Times[a___,1,b___] by Times[a,b]. I think it is pretty unlikely that there is an elegant way of doing things. I had some hope that there would be a way make replacements in a general way, as I believed Power might work in this way. Now I don't think Power works in this way, but I still curious.

As a small remark, not that we of course have

```
MatchQ[f[f[1]], (___f)[1]]
```

-> False

and

```
MatchQ[Unevaluated[Sequence[f, f, f][1]], ___[1]]
```

Repeated and PatternSequence also seemed like they were maybe the way to go. But maybe not.

**The question was**: Is it possible to define a rule in such a way that it determines whether an expression is of the form

```
f[___, f[___, ...[f[___, x_head ,___]] ,___], ___]
```

where the ...[] means that f is applied an arbitrary number of times in this way, and "do something with x on the RHS"?

To clarify, we might want to define something like

```
f[___, f[___, ...[f[___, x_Integer ,___]] ,___], ___]:= x
```

Or in case of power

```
power[power[z...[Times[1,x_]],y_],z1_]:=power[power[z[x],y],z1]
```

where I have given the pattern of "repetitively applying power" the name z.

A way of writing this in that might be parseable by Mathematica could be

```
z...power[Times[1,x_],y_]:=z[x,y]
```

Possibly the answer is: maybe in version 13. But any feedback is welcome :)

Comment: A general advice: stay away from `Unevaluated`, and use `Hold` and friends instead. Another one: things like `Cases[Unevaluated[expr],s:(your-pattern):>Hold[s],Infinity]` should provide sufficient tools to destructure and analyze any expression safely, with no evaluation leaks.

Comment: [This discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5958128/arbitrarily-deep-nested-pattern-matching/) may also be helpful.

Comment: Ah thanks for the feedback :). Yeah passing around multiple Unevaluated's because you think you know when they will be stipped seems like a dangerous idea. I'm sorry if I showed too much of my personal explorations, when the question was really not about this use of Unevaluated. However, I like the construction `With[{something=Unevaluated@@{expr}},_]`. I will now look at that discussion.

Comment: @LeonidShifrin excuse me, it seems I was mistaken about what was going on. See my edits before bending your minds to it :)

Comment: Gosh, that's a long question.  Skimming it, this may be related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11045/121 -- I'll go back to reading now.

Comment: I took at shot at this in an answer below.  I need to get food now, but I'll come back to this later.

Answer (score 1):

#### Second try

Perhaps this is the behavior you are interested in.  If a definition does not match the original expression is returned, with `Unevaluated` intact.  If however the definition is applied the `Unevaluated` is stripped.

```
f[a_, b_] /; NumericQ[a] := {a, b}

f[Unevaluated["inert"], 2]

f[Unevaluated[2 + 2], 2]
```

> ```
> f[Unevaluated["inert"], 2]
>
> {4, 2}
> ```

This could be combined with [Villegas-Gayley](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5149656) to produce behavior similar to your `Power` example:

```
g[a_, b_] /; NumericQ[a] && ! TrueQ[$ginner] := Block[{$ginner = True}, g[a, b]]

g[Unevaluated["inert"], 2]

g[Unevaluated[2 + 2], 2]
```

> ```
> g[Unevaluated["inert"], 2]
>
> g[4, 2]
> ```

---

#### Old answer

I didn't read the majority of your question (sorry) but I will focus on this:

> The question is: Is it possible to define a rule in such a way that it
>   determines whether an expression is of the form
>
> ```
> f[___, f[___, ...[f[___, x_head ,___]] ,___], ___]
> ```
>
> where the ...[] means that f is applied an arbitrary number of times
>   in this way, and "do something with x on the RHS"?

This may be acceptable to you:

```
Hold[ff[ff[ff[ff[ff[gg[1, a1], a2], a3], a4], a5], a6]];

Flatten[%, ∞, ff] /. _[gg[x__], ___] :> found[x]
```

> ```
> found[1, a1]
> ```

If this does *not* work for you I'd appreciate your explaining why directly.

Comment: thanks for looking at it! Sadly, this is not really what I want. In particular, this cannot explain the behavior of Power, as we have that in `Power[Unevalauted[Power[Times[1,2],d]],e]` some rule appears to be applied to strip Times, but if we surround Times or the Power "on the inside" with Hold, nothing happens.

Comment: @Jacob I guess I don't understand what the question is about.  Why are you sticking `Unevaluated` in there?  What are you *actually trying to do*?

Comment: I am trying to see how Power works. I feel this use of Unevaluated can quickly give some idea of what rules MMA will apply. It is my understanding that Unevaluated will only be removed if some rule applies, so you can quickly see if there are rules that apply. But the rule in case of Power seems so unlike anything I have seemed and so powerful, I wanted to learn more about it. I wanted to know if we can make rules like that ourselves. But it turns out I am not sure entirely what the result applying the rule is and what is the result of "normal evaluation of arguments".

Comment: @Jacob I swear I'm not trying to be stupid or suborn, but I don't get it.  "But the rule in case of Power seems so unlike anything I have seemed and so powerful, I wanted to learn more about it." *What* seems so powerful?  Perhaps you are looking for Attributes, such as `Flat`, `Orderless`, `OneIdentity` etc.?

Comment: I am sorry for causing unnecessary confusion by asking so many questions at once. It is the result of that I thought I understood something, which I probably do not understand so well. Compare `Power[Unevaluated[Power[Times[2, a1], a2]], a3]` with `Power[Unevaluated[Power[Times[1, a1], a2]], a3]` In the first case a head Unevaluated remains and in the second case it gets removed. This should have been an example at the start of the question from the beginning.

Comment: @Jacob Thank you; *now* I understand at least part of what you're curious about.  That is indeed unusual.  Perhaps you could rewrite to the question to be far simpler now?

Comment: please see my remark starting with **most importantly**. I think this is the source of a lot of my confusion and it seems to be extremely unusual.

Comment: @Jacob please see my updated answer and tell me if (1) I am addressing the behavior that interests you. (2) I have addressed it satisfactorily.

Comment: Villegas-Gayley seems really nice :). However, for your definition of g we have `g[Unevaluated[{2 + 2}], 2]`-->itself . I do not see how we can extend this to find deeper expressions. +1 but no accept :)

Comment: @Jacob At least I'm getting closer. :^)  My intent was not to fully implement what you're envisioning, whatever that is (sorry, I'm still not "getting it" in full).  Rather, I wanted to show how you might approach this.  I thought evaluating "to itself" was part of what you wanted.  If it's not that, and it's not the `Flatten` aspect shown in my original answer, I'm at a loss for understanding, and I think I'll let someone else take a shot at it.