# Extracting graphics primitives from a Graphics expression with ReplaceAll

Tags: pattern-matching

If we have a graphics object,

```
plt = Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, Pi}]
```

and we need to retrieve the discrete point data from it. This can be easily done by using `Extract` and `Position`,

```
First@Extract[plt, Most@First@Position[plt, Line]]
```

Or using `Cases`,

```
First@Cases[plt, Line[data_] -> data, Infinity]
```

However, my question is, might this be done via generic pattern matching? For example, some code like

```
plt /. (patterns-for-any-nested-or-parallel-heads) __ [ ___, Line[data_], ___] :> data
```

It might not be difficult to handle the parallel heads, but I do not see a obvious way to deal with the nested heads in a generic manner. Of course we can manually type all the nested heads, but this is rather specific. I am exploring the capacity of pattern matching in Mathematica. Is it possible to figure a general way to make Mathematica does it by itself? Actually I think this might be part of the algorithm under the hood of `Cases`.

Comment: Could you give simple examples of a nested case and a parallel case? And what exactly we would be trying to find in those examples?

Comment: The question is, do you want to get the points *via* `ReplaceAll` or do you want to create the pattern that will fulfill the `MatchQ` with the `Graphics` but where only `Line` is explicitely used.

Comment: For the first step, we can just try to pick out the discrete point data from plt, using pattern matching.

Comment: @saturasl So in other words, how can we do the exact same thing `Cases` is doing without using `Cases` but instead using `/.`?

Comment: `plt //. _[___, x_Line, ___] :> x`

Comment: @mfvonh, Yes, this could be enlightening.

Comment: @Kuba, thanks, your code is a third way to get the points. But it highly exploits the built-in functions of Mathematica, like `Cases`. I am looking for a way to do this using simple pattern matching only with `ReplaceAll`.

Comment: @Jacob Akkerboom, Thank you in advance.

Comment: @saturasl @Kuba's way is how I would do it with patterns, but I understand what you're asking. I don't know how to achieve that with `/.` (I'll mull it over.) But concerning your original question, I don't think that is how `Cases` is implemented. My guess is the algorithm looks more like `Reap[Scan[If[MatchQ[#, _Line], Sow[#]] &, plt, \[Infinity]]]`.

Comment: @mfvonh, Any insight is welcome, because I am trying to get sharper understanding of Mathematica...

Comment: It is appropriate to point out an important difference between `Cases` and `Replace(All)` here.  The former walks the expression tree from inside out (leaves first, root last), while `ReplaceAll` goes the other way: outside first, then the leaves of the tree last.  Yes, one of them can emulate the other, but this difference will always persist.  **Also:* Your question implies that `ReplaceAll` is somehow more fundamental ("generic pattern matching") than `Cases`.  I wouldn't say this is the case and I'm pretty sure internally one isn't implemented in terms of the other.

Comment: Reference: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8700934/695132

Comment: @Szabolcs can `Map`, `Scan` etc. be directed to walk depth-first?

Comment: @mfvonh I don't think it can be controlled in what order they traverse the expression, but you can always use level specifications to restrict them to work only on certain levels, and you can do multiple calls, e.g. `Do[Scan[Print, expr, {i}], {i, 0, Depth[expr]}]`.

Comment: The most effective method is to use `Cases` which is what I use. A `Graphics` object describes a [state machine](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32717/52), and if you want something that captures the structure, use a [parser](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/32719/52). But, usually that is overkill, so stick with `Cases`.

Comment: @Szabolcs, I intuitively agree with you about your insight on `Cases` and `ReplaceAll`. Although they all follow the standard evaluation procedure of Mathematica - each expression is evaluated until no further definitions apply - they may be controlled differently by kernel. It is a pity that there is little talk about the internal algorithm. I believe that my question can be solved by using a similiar code like the built-in code for `Trace` which has very amazing capabilities with various options, like `TraceAbove` and `TraceOriginal`.

Comment: @rcollyer, From the result point of view, your parser partly resembles the combination of `Extract` and `Position`. I like it, because it is a beautiful attack to reveal the internal of Mathematica, to some extent. This is very useful to me, thank you.

Comment: Related to Szabolcs's comment, and possibly of interest: [(9209)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9209), [(9233)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9233)

Comment: Related, I believe: [(6451802)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6451802),
[(11045)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11045),
[(23730)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23730)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Other than the fact that `ReplaceAll` and `Cases` traverse expressions differently, as mentioned by Szabolcs in a comment (see [(9209)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9209), [(9233)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/9233)), you could use [`Throw`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Throw.html) and [`Catch`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Catch.html):

```
r1 = First@Cases[plt, Line[data_] :> data, Infinity];

r2 = plt /. Line[data_] :> Throw[data] // Catch;

r1 === r2
```

> ```
> True
> ```

For multiple matches you could use [`Sow`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Sow.html) and [`Reap`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reap.html), along with [`RuleCondition`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/29319/121) to handle held expressions, as in:

```
plt2 = Plot[{Sin[x], Cos[x], Sinc[x]}, {x, 0, 5}];

Short /@
 Reap[
   plt2 /. Line[data_] :> RuleCondition @ Sow @ data;
 ][[2, 1]]
```

> ```
> {{{1.02041*10^-7,1.02041*10^-7},<<405>>,{5.,-0.958924}},
>  {{1.02041*10^-7,1.},<<335>>,{5.,0.283662}},
>  {{1.02041*10^-7,1.},<<325>>,{5.,-0.191785}}}
> ```

If for some reason you don't want to use `Throw`, `Catch`, `Sow`, or `Reap` you could manually accumulate these expressions, but there is little point in such an exercise as far as I can see.  (Or you could use the lower-level [`StuffBag`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=StuffBag) if that interests you.)

Comment: Concise and enlightening, you have my gratitude!

Comment: `Throw`, `Catch`, `Sow`, and `Reap` can be used almost anywhere in any code, such powerful attribute might also be heavily used in the built-in code of `Trace`, and I think they are at very fundamental level of Mathematica language.